# How OOM(out of memory excepetion) happens in android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-bitmap

I am trying to display an image from gallery or captured form camera in a `ImageView`. I started getting `OOM`s in the process. So I decided to find out how this works. So I tried with different size images here are the observations,

I tried to load a 19KB image into the `ImageView` and got the following error message.
Failed to allocate a 4915212 byte allocation with 570452 free bytes and 557KB until `OOM` with a 2MB image I got 
Failed to allocate a 31961100 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 29MB until `OOM` 2MB

Why a 19KB  image require almost a 4.6MB in main memory and 2MB image require a 30 MB main memory space?

PS: I found a lot of solutions like down-sampling the image as per the display, none of them explained this behavior.

Comment: You've got good answers from @Henry and @dumazy, also you can see my post for understanding how to avoid `OOM`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763405/bitmap-copy-throws-out-of-memory-error/24034816#24034816

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally you will be using `ARGB_8888` for bitmap. This means for each pixel 4 bytes are allocated (each one for A, R, G, B). It means that loading 1024x768 image takes 1024*768*4 = 3145728 B = 3072 KB = 3 MB. This is the reason why huge memory is used. The following info is taken from the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html

**Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8** - Each pixel is stored as a single translucency (alpha) channel.

**Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444** -This field was deprecated in API level 13. Because of the poor quality of this configuration, it is advised to use ARGB_8888 instead.
**Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888** - Each pixel is stored on 4 bytes.

**Bitmap.Config.RGB_565** - Each pixel is stored on 2 bytes and only the RGB channels are encoded: red is stored with 5 bits of precision (32 possible values), green is stored with 6 bits of precision (64 possible values) and blue is stored with 5 bits of precision.

Answer (score 2):

In Android every pixel of an image requires 4 bytes of memory. So if you create a `Bitmap` out of a 5 megapixel image, you'll need about 20MB. Therefore, you should calculate the required sample size to display the image without loading in the complete resolution.

Even if the image file is only 19KB, the `Bitmap` object will take up more memory.

Try creating a static method to calculate the required sample size:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
}
```

and then check the bounds of the image first, before loading in the complete image:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

More info on this is found in the developer guide:
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: `4 bytes of memory    `
8 bytes, or no?