# Alternative to createBitmap in android ,Createbitmap() takes a lot of time

Tags: android

Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, false);
takes a lot of time and causes memory issues.Any better way to createbitmap in android?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for posting.  It would be really helpful if you could add some code and some more details about what you've tried and what, exactly, your problem is.  That will help people to quickly find your problem and give a better answer.  Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no. This is the only API that you use to create `Bitmap`. The time taken depends on the size of the bitmap. Try to keep the size as low as possible. In any case, you need to do this operation in the background. Do not execute this in the UI thread.

Also, when possible try to reuse the old bitmap instead of creating new ones. The other thing is to use the right `Config` when creating the Bitmap. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33342074/4747587

If you are using the bitmap to display content to user and not to save in file system then refer this: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html